# Converting a Fortran statement to PHP

Tags: php, fortran77

I am not good at computer programming and have a problem in understanding a Fortran statement. I would like to convert the following statement in Fortran into PHP. Really appreciate your help!

```
PARAMETER (a=10  ,b=6)
CHARACTER*5 WE(a)
```

1) What does `CHARACTER*5 WE(a)` mean in Fortran?
2) How can I write it in PHP?

Thanks

Comment: Fortran to PHP!? Uhmm, you sure you got that correct?

Comment: yes, I have a Fortran code and wanna convert it to PHP. Those two statements are written in Fortran.

Answer (score 2):

Your first line of Fortran code `PARAMETER (a=10  ,b=6)` can be written in PHP as:

```
<?php
define('a', 10);
define('b', 5);
?>
```

Those are called **constants**, a special type of variable that will not change during execution of the program.

Your second line of Fortran code `CHARACTER*5 WE(a)` isn't portable to a PHP program (and it isn't needed, as well), because PHP will dynamically allocate memory for your arrays, and so you can't have an array with pre-determined size.

Answer (score 0):

`CHARACTER*5 WE(a)` declares an array of `a` elements, each element being a character variable of length 5.